# Adjoint of a linear map in the quotient space

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

It should be explained somewhere but I cannot find it. Would you let me know where I can find the definition? Specifically, my question is

> Let $V$ be a subspace of $R^n$ and $R^n/V$ be a quotient space. How is the adjoint of a linear map $A:R^n/V\to R^n/V$ defined?

I guess that this question contains a problem to define the inner product in the quotient space.

Comment: Well, **exactly** the same as usual, of course:  the space $\;\Bbb R^n/V\;$ is a linear space so you can define linear operators on it. Anyway, what adjoint did you mean? The classical adjoint, also named "adjugate matrix", or the adjoint $\;T^*\;$ for an operator on a linear space with inner product?

Comment: @DonAntonio I meant the second one that satisfies the relation $\langle A[x],[y]\rangle = \langle [x],A^*[y]\rangle$ where $[x],[y]\in R^n/V$. But I don't know how to define the inner product in $R^n/V$. Is there a natural definition?

Comment: Ah, well: that precisely is the question. How are you going to define an inner product in the quotient space? For one, you'd need a symmetric positive definite bilinear form from which to construct your inner product...

Comment: @flyingwith: I don't understand your question: it seems that what you want to ask is not about operators, but about how to induce a scalar product on a quotient space from a scalar product on the larger space, right?

Comment: @AlexM. Probably, I should mention that there are two questions: 1) what is the definition of the adjoint in $R^n/V$ and 2) what is the definition of the inner product in $R^n/V$. I thought 1) includes 2).

Comment: @DonAntonio I may define the inner product in $R^n/V$ by myself like $\langle [x],[y]\rangle_{R^n/V} = \langle [x]\cap V^\perp,[y]\cap V^\perp\rangle_{R^n}$ but I want to know a textbook definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try the following, **assuming we already have an inner product** $\;\langle,\rangle\;$ defined on $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ to begin with, since then we know $\;\color{red}{(*)}\;\;\Bbb R^n=V\oplus V^\perp\;$ and we could "identify" the quotient $\;\Bbb R^n/V\;$ with the orthogonal complement $\;V^\perp\;$ of $\;V\;$ .

Why this works? Because if we're to define a new inner product $\;\langle .\rangle_q\;$ on $\;\Bbb R^n/V\;$ , we want that

$$x_1+V=x_2+V\implies \langle x_1+V,\,w+V\rangle_q=\langle x_2+V,\,w+V\rangle_q\;,\;\;\forall\;x_1,\,x_2,\,w\in\Bbb R^n$$

but observe that, using the equality $\;\color{red}{(*)}\;$ above, we can (**uniquely**) write *for any* $\;x\in\Bbb R^n\;$ :

$$x=v_x+u_x\;,\;\;v_x\in V\;,\;\;u_x\in V^\perp\;$$

and if we *then* define $\;\langle x+V,\,w+V\rangle_q:=\langle u_x,\,u_w\rangle\;$

we then get :

$$ \langle u_{x_1},\,u_w\rangle=:\langle x_1+V,\,w+V\rangle_q=\langle x_2+V,\,w+V\rangle_q:=\langle u_{x_2},\,u_w\rangle\iff$$

$$\langle u_{x_1}-u_{x_2},\,u_w\rangle=0\iff u_{x_1}-u_{x_2}\in V\;\text{ (since $\;u_w\in V^\perp\;$ is arbitrary!)}\iff$$

$$u_{x_1}=u_{x_2}\;,\;\;\text{because}\;\;V\cap V^\perp=\{0\}$$

Comment: It's not that "we can try the following", it's that this is the canonical way of thinking about it (even when dealing with general Hilbert spaces, and $V$ a closed subspace). I was writing the same when you posted it, so I discarded my draft.

Comment: @AlexM. Perhaps. Truly, that's the most "natural" way I saw it from the beginning after finding out what "adjoint" the OP meant, yet he didn't add much info...Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for your answer.